# How to make a Round Toolbar for a Website

Tags: html

I'v searched the whole time for about 3 days to make a round toolbar then i'v tried to do it myselt but i could'nt. Then my friend said to me about Stackoverflow that they are amazing at answering html Questions. And this what i want to do: [Round Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtJ5x.jpg)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you searched for "round toolbar" that were propably not the best keywords for what you want, something like "css circular menu" is much more suitable.

One of the first results when using Google provides you with anything you dreamed of, giving the solution ready to copy&paste as well as explaining step by step how to get there:
https://css-tricks.com/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-clip-paths/

There is even an online generator: https://sarasoueidan.com/tools/circulus/
and a guide on how to include the generated svg file so that it can actually be used as a menu.

Good luck!

Comment: why is this being downvoted..
and you're welcome!